# Position of Virtual Keyboard plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, virtual-keyboard

I'm using this plugin (http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-screen-keyboard-plugin/#.UCTg6p1lTkd) to create an on-screen keyboard for a Kiosk. It works great, however I need the keyboard to appear at the bottom of the screen not below the input/text area.

Within the external jquery.keyboard.js file I've found the following:

```
$.keyboard.defaultOptions = {

        // *** choose layout & positioning ***
        layout       : 'qwerty',
        customLayout : null,

        position     : {
            of : null, // optional - null (attach to input/textarea) or a jQuery object (attach elsewhere)
            my : 'center top',
            at : 'center top',
            at2: 'center bottom' // used when "usePreview" is false (centers the keyboard at the bottom of the input/textarea)
        },
```

What should I be using instead of 'null'? How should this be added to the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For the `of` parameter, just target the document window: `$(window)`.

Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/MK947/667/) and the code:

```
$('#keyboard').keyboard({

    // Used by jQuery UI position utility
    position: {
        of: $(window), // null = attach to input/textarea; use $(sel) to attach elsewhere
        my: 'center bottom',
        at: 'center bottom',
        at2: 'center bottom' // used when "usePreview" is false
    }

});​
```

Since this is for a kiosk, you might to also want to check out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Em8sG/624/) which positioned and resized the keyboard. Also, previous and next buttons are added within the keyboard... hmm, I swear there was a previous and next button. I'll need to update that demo.

Note: I added a tag for `virtual-keyboard` because I completely missed this question. Also be sure to check out the [documentation](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki).